# Keep the domain name and change to wordpress

Tags: domain

The company I work for currently has its website up through a website agency. Since I don't like how they work and cost way too much, I want to do the whole website in wordpress. I want to keep the domain-name.

Is it easy to change this? What do I need from them? How do I do this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh and I don't think they are using wordpress, yet some kind of CMS of their own. No idea where they are hosting. They are hard to talk to.

Comment: Of course you can do it easily. Just you need to [Pointing Your Domain Name To A Different Host Company](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sva42KVt0-o). Keep in mind if your site is not in #WORDPRESS then you have to put all data manually from old side you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's easy to change CMSs. It's mainly a process of learning WordPress and copying all the content over. Here's the general process you'll need to follow:

1. Make sure you control the domain name. As in, it's registered by your company and not the agency. If it is registered by the agency, stop here and get it transferred into your company's name so that you will be able to log in and change DNS (the server where it points).
2. Also make sure you control the hosting or have a new host in mind. As long as you control the domain, you can either buy new hosting and point the domain to the new host, or possibly continue hosting with the agency, depending on their server setup.
3. Set up a staging site. This is a fully working copy of your website. You'll install WordPress, add a theme, add some plugins, customize the site, and add all the content. This is likely to be a manual, time-consuming process, depending on how big the site is. You should set up the staging site on the desired host (see step 2) to make sure everything works as expected. You'll also want to plan out redirects, so that your old URLs will redirect to your new URLs. If possible, keep the same URL structure.
4. Once all is working well on the staging site, back everything up, then use a database migration plugin to change from the staging URL to your actual domain.
5. If you're staying on the same hosting, back up and move the files from the old CMS so that WordPress becomes the new default.

If you're switching to a new host, you'll need to log in to your domain registrar and update DNS settings, so the domain changes from pointing to the agency host to the new host. It varies, but can take 24-48 hours for everything to switch over. You may or may not be able to log in during that time, so it sometimes helps to flip the switch on a Friday, have the weekend for DNS resolution, and come back Monday to your fresh new website, ready for edits.

Comment: Thank you! You are an absolute legend for answering to clear yet concise!